# How do I use try statements in R?

Tags: r, try-catch

So I'm trying to loop through some data and use them in my code. The place where I need this try thing is at the following:

```
for (number in numbers) {
    CTV_volume <- CTV[ which(CTV$Key==number), ]$volume
    PTV_volume <- PTV[ which(PTV$Key==number), ]$volume
    ITV_volume <- ITV[ which(ITV$Key==numbers), ]$volume

    large_volume <- large_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(CTV_volume), a_large, b_large)
    small_volume <- small_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(CTV_volume), a_small, b_small) 
}
```

The thing is that the `CTV_volume` calculation in the two last lines (`large_volume` and `small_volume`) depends on data from the first line above (`CTV_volume`). However, for each iteration of the loop there is a chance that there is no CTV for that particular key/number, and instead I need to use another one, i.e. ITV. But first and foremost I need it to use the CTV first if that is present, and if not, then the ITV word.

How is that accomplished in R?

Comment: It is very easy. Try “if”. Also, since you loop then you need to save your values in a list or vector.

Comment: But can I use if statements with error ? For example, when I run the code, and run into a place where the CTV doesn't exist I get the "value" `numeric(0)` instead of a number. Can one use an if statement on such a "value" ?

Comment: you can test for the length of an object being 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get back an empty vector i.e. `numeric(0)` it technically is not an error.

So if you use `tryCatch()` as shown below, the result will not change.

```
for (number in numbers) {
  CTV_volume <- CTV[ which(CTV$Key==number), ]$volume
  PTV_volume <- PTV[ which(PTV$Key==number), ]$volume
  ITV_volume <- ITV[ which(ITV$Key==numbers), ]$volume

  tryCatch({
    large_volume <- large_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(CTV_volume), a_large, b_large)
    small_volume <- small_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(CTV_volume), a_small, b_small)
    },
    error = function(e) {
      #what should be done in case of exeption?
      str(e) # prints structure of exeption
      large_volume <- large_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(ITV_volume), a_large, b_large)
      small_volume <- small_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(ITV_volume), a_small, b_small) 
    }
  )
}
```

Instead what you probably want to do is check if `CTV_volume` has the expected length.

```
for (number in numbers) {
  CTV_volume <- CTV[ which(CTV$Key==number), ]$volume
  PTV_volume <- PTV[ which(PTV$Key==number), ]$volume
  ITV_volume <- ITV[ which(ITV$Key==numbers), ]$volume

  if (length(CTV_volume) > 0) {
    large_volume <- large_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(CTV_volume), a_large, b_large)
    small_volume <- small_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(CTV_volume), a_small, b_small) 
  } else {
    large_volume <- large_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(ITV_volume), a_large, b_large)
    small_volume <- small_margin_vol_calc(radius_calc(ITV_volume), a_small, b_small) 
  }
}
```